# ¿ Como puedo hacer un buscador autocompletable en java eclipse con registros de una base de datos en Access?

Tags: base-de-datos, eclipse, ms-access, jtextfield, buscador

```js
package src1;

importjava.awt.EventQueue;
importjava.sql.Connection;
importjava.sql.ResultSet;
importjava.sql.Statement;
importjavax.swing.JFrame;
importjavax.swing.JOptionPane;
importjavax.swing.JPanel;
importjavax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
importcom.mxrck.autocompleter.TextAutoCompleter;
importjavax.swing.JTextField;
importjavax.swing.JLabel;
importjava.awt.Font;

publicclassprueba3extendsJFrame {

    privateJPanelcontentPane;
    privateJTextFieldtx;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    publicstaticvoid main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(newRunnable() {
            publicvoid run() {
                try {
                    prueba3frame = new prueba3();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public prueba3() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 474, 411);
        contentPane = newJPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(newEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);
        
        tx = newJTextField();
        tx.setBounds(25, 44, 407, 20);
        contentPane.add(tx);
        tx.setColumns(10);
        
        JLabellblNombreDelProveedor = newJLabel("NOMBRE DEL PROVEEDOR:");
        lblNombreDelProveedor.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 14));
        lblNombreDelProveedor.setBounds(136, 11, 185, 26);
        contentPane.add(lblNombreDelProveedor);

        items();
    }
publicvoid items () {
    
    TextAutoCompleterAutocompletar = newTextAutoCompleter(tx);  
    
    Connection Conectar = ConexionAccess.obtenerConexion();    
    
        Statement st=null;
    ResultSetrs=null;

    try {
        
        st = (Statement)Conectar.createStatement();
        rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM MODELO WHERE PROVEEDOR = '"+tx+"'");
        
        while (rs.next());  {       
        
        Autocompletar.addItem(rs.getString("PROVEEDOR"));
        
              }
               } catch(Exception de)
                           {
            JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this, de.getMessage());
    
}
     }
}
```

```js
package src1;

importjava.sql.Connection;
importjava.sql.DriverManager;

importjavax.swing.JOptionPane;

publicclassConexionAccess {
    
    static Connection con = null;
    static String driver = "net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver";
    static String url = "jdbc:ucanaccess://C:\\Users\\Estadias\\workspace\\Catalogo De Proveedores\\Proveedores.accdb";
    
    publicstatic Connection obtenerConexion() {
    try {
        if(con==null) {
            Class.forName(driver);
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ConectadoCorrectamente");
         }
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        con = null; 
    }
    returncon;
    }
    
    publicstaticvoid main(String[]args) {
        
        
    }

}
```

> Cita en bloque.

Es mi primer codigo y la verdad no conozco mucho sobre programacion, por eso necesito de su ayuda, se los agradeceria bastante.

Debo hacer un buscador que autocomplete las palabras utilizando una base de datos en access de 13,000 registros y esto es un poco de lo que e investigado, sin embargo no me deja de marcar errores que me indican que el cursor no esta indicando ninguna fila aunque escriba los nombres de las columnas tal y como estan en la B.D.
Para esto estoy utilizando la libreria `TextAutocomplete` sobre un `Jtextfield` y para la conexion java-access una llamada ucanaccess.
Tambien utilizo como apoyo el [windowbuilder](/questions/tagged/windowbuilder)

[image]Esta es mi Base de Datos, y quiero que el buscador me muestre unicamente datos de la columna "PROVEEDOR"

[image: );]Uno de los errores que me suele aparecer es este y segun entiendo tiene que ver con la siguiente linea de codigo:  rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM MODELO WHERE PROVEEDOR = '"+tx+"'"

[image]Seguido de que me aparezca dicho error, el programa me arroja la ventana pero es inservible

Comment: Entiendo que al copiar el código esta mal formateado ya que veo cosas como `publicclassConexionAccess`. ¿Podrías dar algo mas de información del error que te da? En que linea de código, mensaje exacto de la excepción,etc. Un saludo

Comment: Te doy la idea: Luego que hayas pasado las 3 letras (por efectos de rendimiento), lanzas en cada "onkeyup" una query que tiene un select nombre from tablaProveedor where nombre like...

Comment: @fredyfx podrias darme un ejemplo

Comment: @ElGerar e agregado nueva informacion espero sea de utilidad

Comment: @CesarMata desconozco bro, la idea es la que buscas. Considerando que son 13mil proveedores, mejor el autocompletar lo ejecutas con 4 letras en lugar de 3, menos resultados. Tienes que verificar la longitud del texto que estás ingresando y un evento onkeyup o keypress o keyrelease o algo que maneje las pulsaciones del teclado

Comment: @fredyfx Ah vale ya entiendo, gracias bro enserio me sera de utilidad

Comment: con cariño hermano, mira, cuando lo hagas funcionar, publica la respuesta aquí mismo (en la parte de abajo donde hay una área de texto para ello) y le será de utilida a más desarrolladores, serás el héroe de la comunidad en este tipo de casos :D ¡Tú puedes!